# Shopify Hydrogen and React Server Components

Tags: shopify, shopify-hydrogen

```
[dev] You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
[dev] Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials
[dev]
[dev]    ,-[[***]frontend\node_modules\@shopify\hydrogen-react\dist\node-dev\AddToCartButton.mjs:1:1]
[dev]  1 | import { jsxs, Fragment, jsx } from "react/jsx-runtime";
[dev]  2 | import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
[dev]    :                    ^^^^^^^^^
[dev]  3 | import { useCart } from "./CartProvider.mjs";
[dev]  4 | import { useProduct } from "./ProductProvider.mjs";
[dev]  5 | import { BaseButton } from "./BaseButton.mjs";
[dev]    `----
[dev]
[dev] Maybe one of these should be marked as a client entry with "use client":
[dev]   ./node_modules\@shopify\hydrogen-react\dist\node-dev\AddToCartButton.mjs
[dev]   ./node_modules\@shopify\hydrogen-react\dist\node-dev\index.mjs
[dev]   ./src\clients\storefront\client.ts
[dev]   ./src\clients\storefront\requests\getProduct.ts
[dev]   ./src\app\[locale]\[...slug]\page.tsx
```

We are trying to import a client from react-hydrogen package into our NextJS 14 app, below import causes the above error:

```
import { createStorefrontClient } from '@shopify/hydrogen-react';
```

but when I change import to directly get the client like that:

```
import { createStorefrontClient } from '@shopify/hydrogen-react/storefront-client';
```

Everything works fine, does anyone have any idea why it tries to import a component that isn't imported anywhere in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Not that old issue where Nextjs had problems that resulted in the tree shaking not working with Typescript barrel files

This PR in NextJS repo fixes the issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/60246

- Solution, update NextJS to the latest version